# Cannot open firefox on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, firefox, error-handling

I just used archinstall to install arch in VirtualBox with the xorg profile and also installed `htop`, `neofetch` and `firefox`. When I typed `htop` into the command line, `htop` launched:

[image: here's htop]

That looks, normal right? But when I typed `firefox`, I got an error:

```
error:no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

[image: here's the error too]

Comment: Are you actually having X11 in use? It appears from your screenshots that you are not using a GUI running in the VM but are using a terminal. You should describe how you are accessing the VM.

Comment: Yes, Arch won't install a graphical environment by default. Now, installing firefox might have brought the relevant packages in, but you would still need to launch X or at least reboot and see if it now presents you with a graphical login. But you won't be able to run graphical tools like firefox without a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to [install a desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_environment) which makes use of a ‘display manager’. Without said display manager you will have no DISPLAY environment value and so GUI programs won’t really have much to work with.